# How to Force login Facebook using FB C# SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using FB SDK in .net, and on my website there are multiple Facebook emails configured by the user. 
Whenever the user wants to post any message on FB, he can pick any email and should be able to login on FB.

The problem is that if the user already logged-in in to FB but wants to post message on some other FB account we are not able to show him the login screen and  the message gets posted on the already logged-in account.

Even though we have users `auth_type=reauthenticate` but this also didn't help to show login screen each time. I need a mechanism like on twitter to force login on FB.

Can anyone please provide help?

Answer (score 1):

1. A Facebook App  – Take note of your App ID and App Secret
2. Json.NET Installed in your Bin. Download Here: http://json.codeplex.com
3. The following references need to be added to the page your app will be set up on:

   using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
     using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Security.Cryptography;
4. This is the HTML content:

   ```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
   ```

   ```
   function runLogin() {
   FB.init({
   appId  : 'ENTERYOURAPPIDHERE',
   status : true,
   cookie : true,
   xfbml  : true,
   channelURL: 'ENTERTHEPAGEYOURAPPURLPOINTSTOHERE', // channel.html file 
   oauth : true 
   });
   ```

   ```
   <div id="dontLike">
       PAGE IS <b>NOT</b> Liked
   </div>

   </form>
   ```

Open up your code-behind for the page. We validated the code signed request.

```
public bool ValidateSignedRequest()
    {
        var VALID_SIGNED_REQUEST = Request.Form["signed_request"];

        string applicationSecret = "YOURAPPSECRET";
        string[] signedRequest = VALID_SIGNED_REQUEST.Split('.');
        string expectedSignature = signedRequest[0];
        string payload = signedRequest[1];

        // Attempt to get same hash
        var Hmac = SignWithHmac(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload), UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(applicationSecret));
        var HmacBase64 = ToUrlBase64String(Hmac);

        return (HmacBase64 == expectedSignature);
    }

   private string ToUrlBase64String(byte[] Input)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Input).Replace("=", String.Empty)
                                            .Replace('+', '-')
                                            .Replace('/', '_');
    }

    private byte[] SignWithHmac(byte[] dataToSign, byte[] keyBody)
    {
        using (var hmacAlgorithm = new HMACSHA256(keyBody))
        {
            hmacAlgorithm.ComputeHash(dataToSign);
            return hmacAlgorithm.Hash;
        }
    }

 public Dictionary<string, string> DecodePayload(string payload)
    {
        //Remove the bad part of signed_request
        //Begin
        string[] sB64String = payload.Split('.');
        payload = payload.Replace((sB64String[0] + "."), string.Empty);
        //End
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var decodedJson = payload.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
        var base64JsonArray = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedJson.PadRight(decodedJson.Length + (4 - decodedJson.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
        var json = encoding.GetString(base64JsonArray);
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        parameters.Add("page", ((bool)jObject["page"]["liked"]).ToString());
        parameters.Add("admin", ((bool)jObject["page"]["admin"]).ToString());
        return parameters;
    }

protected void pageLike()
    {
        string pageLiked = string.Empty;
        var signed_request = Request.Form["signed_request"];
        var json = DecodePayload(signed_request);


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> objKVP in json)
        {
            //Note You can also see if a user is an admin by replacing the objKVP.Key with admin
            if (objKVP.Key == "page" && objKVP.Value == "True")
            {
                Response.Redirect("https://www.YOURSITE.com/facebook/app/pageLiked.aspx");
                litJson.Text += objKVP.Key + " - " + objKVP.Value + "<br />";
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        pageLike();
    }
```

You can see this example at this link: http://blog.daniellecopp.com/2012/03/19/detect-if-facebook-user-likes-your-page-with-asp-net-2/#comment-52

Comment: nice, but you might need to provide a summary of that link in your answer should that link expire

Comment: Thank for your reply, we need to implement that practices.